# AMPscript code for showing nothing if the condition was not met

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I would like to display an HTML block to a subscriber based on his customer_type status, using an IF statement. However, not all subscribers have the above field filled (there are some with NULL values). For these subscribers, I'd like to not display anything (especially not an error), and just "skip" that part of the code / move on to the next HTML block.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```vb
%%[
    VAR @contentBlockID, @SubscriberType

    SET @SubscriberType = SubscriberType
    IF @SusbcriberType == "XY" THEN
        SET @contentBlockID = 1794204 
    ELSEIF @SubscriberType == "XZ" THEN
        SET @contentBlockID = 1794311 
    ENDIF
]%%

%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the variable is empty. Depending on the result you fetch the content block or not.

```vb
%%[ IF NOT Empty(@contentBlockID) THEN ]%%
    %%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

A complete example would look like this:

```vb
%%[
    VAR @contentBlockID, @SubscriberType

    SET @SubscriberType = AttributeValue("SubscriberType")
    IF @SusbcriberType == "XY" THEN
        SET @contentBlockID = "1794204"
    ELSEIF @SubscriberType == "XZ" THEN
        SET @contentBlockID = "1794311"
    ENDIF

    IF NOT Empty(@contentBlockID) THEN
]%%
    %%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Markus,Great. Seems logical. However, I'm getting an error. Is it possible to include it in the first AMPscript block, or am I not understanding how to use it? :-)

Comment: This is supposed to be a replacement for `%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%`. If you want to include it in the first block, just remove the opening `%%[` and the ending `]%%` and place below your last `ENDIF`. However your code is possibly not fully functional as it is, maybe you like to use `SET @SubscriberType = AttributeValue("SubscriberType")` in the line before your IF-statement.

Comment: Markus, you're the man. I've just applied the complete example, and it worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!! ;-)

Comment: You are welcome, glad I cloud help! ;)